# Copying compiled PHP extension

Tags: php, apache, phalcon, php-extension

I have a VPS with 512MB memory, I tried compiling phalcon PHP framework on it however it runs out of memory.
I decided to create a new VPS with larger memory and compile phalcon on it, then copy the shared library to the 512MB server.

The problem is php is not loading the extension at all!

contents of /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/30-phalcon.ini

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

Both servers have the same environment, and same dependencies installed on both.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this, for future reference, I was checking the extension_loaded() from the CLI and I had to add the extension loading configuration to /etc/php5/cli/conf.d